# how do i get rid of these duplicate records and select only the highest date from each one?

Tags: sql

i need to use this query to return records with the most recent NoteDate, instead of returning duplicate records showing each note date. i thought that putting the 'MAX' in front of t.notedate would get rid of the duplicate records but they still show up.

```
SELECT    c.ContactId,  MAX(t.notedate),c.Source, c.FirstName, c.LastName,  c.Phone1, crCallResultCode, crTotalCallCount

FROM         dbo.t_Contact c inner join t_notes t on c.contactid=t.contactid

WHERE     

(c.Source IN ('Cabo10MC', 'BOWN10')) AND 
 (c.crCallResultCode NOT IN ('V02', 'S01', 'CNC', 'R99','U01', 'U02', 'U03')) AND 
 (DATEDIFF(ww, crNextCallDateTime, GETDATE()) = 0)OR (crNextCallDateTime = '1/1/1900')AND 
 (c.Phone1 NOT IN
                          (SELECT     phone
                            FROM          lema.dbo.tswlivetours
                            WHERE      TourDate > getdate() AND TourStatus IN ('showed')))

group by c.ContactId,  c.Source, c.FirstName, c.LastName,  c.Phone1, crCallResultCode, crTotalCallCount,t.notedate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove t.notedate from your group by clause.

```
...group by c.ContactId,  c.Source, c.FirstName, c.LastName,  c.Phone1, crCallResultCode, crTotalCallCount
```